# Knex.js | running 'knex seed:run' twice gives error because of foreign key

Tags: knex.js

My 'users' table has a reference to the 'business' table.

When I run `knex seed:run` twice I get the following error:

> error: update or delete on table "businesses" violates foreign key
>   constraint "users_business_id_foreign" on table "users"

My current seed looks like this:

```
exports.seed = (knex, Promise) =>
    knex('businesses').del()
        .then(() =>
            knex('businesses').insert([
                {...
```

What's the conventional way to solve this problem with Knex.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on database, which you are using. But the conventional way in `knex` is exactly the same that is conventional way generally when working with SQL databases.

Here are some ways to do it (there are probably many more valid ways to do this):

- Delete first that table data, which is referencing your business table
- Delete all tables in single `.with` statement (foreign key constraint is checked only after running the query in postgresql)
- Delete all tables inside transaction and set checking foreign key constraints off first (mysql)
- Truncate all tables and sequences in single `TRUNCATE` statement (postgresql)